# Convert this VB code to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me convert the below code to c#? From what I have read it seems to be similar however I am not sure if my 'case' statements are still able to be used?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim dteStart As Date
    Dim dteFinish As Date
    Dim span As TimeSpan

    Public Sub KeyDown(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  _
    System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Q
                Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
                dteStart = Now()
            Case Keys.W
                Label2.BackColor = Color.Green
            Case Keys.E
                Label3.BackColor = Color.Green
            Case Keys.R
                Label4.BackColor = Color.Green
                dteFinish = Now()
                span = dteFinish.Subtract(dteStart)
                Label5.Text = span.ToString

        End Select

    End Sub

    Public Sub KeyUp(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  _
   System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp

        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Q
                Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
            Case Keys.W
                Label2.BackColor = Color.Red
            Case Keys.E
                Label3.BackColor = Color.Red
            Case Keys.R
                Label4.BackColor = Color.Red
        End Select

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Is this VB.NET? If so, conversion should be trivial, using find and replace.

Comment: @Mr Lister according to System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs, this is a VB.NET KeyDown event handler

Comment: in C# you looking for the switch statement, quick glance and conversion will be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use online tools for converting C# to Vb or vice versa

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 4):

This is not the place for "Do this for me" requests. For this, you can hire a programmer.

This is place to ask for advice or guidance after you already tried something on your own.

Anyway, I will show you how to convert `Select Case` to its C# equivalent, you can take it from there.

Sample code for one of the statements:

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.Q:
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        break;
    case Keys.W:
        Label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        break;
    //.....
}
```

Things to notice:

1. Like anything in C#, case matters - so for example `Case` must become `case`.
2. You have to add `break` after each case.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Form1
{

    System.DateTime dateStart;
    System.DateTime dteFinish;

    TimeSpan span;

    public void KeyDown(System.Object Sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.Q:
                Label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                dteStart = DateAndTime.Now();
                break;
            case Keys.W:
                Label2.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case Keys.E:
                Label3.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case Keys.R:
                Label4.BackColor = Color.Green;
                dteFinish = DateAndTime.Now();
                span = dteFinish.Subtract(dteStart);
                Label5.Text = span.ToString();

                break;
        }

    }


    public void KeyUp(System.Object Sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.Q:
                Label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Keys.W:
                Label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Keys.E:
                Label3.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Keys.R:
                Label4.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        KeyUp += KeyUp;
        KeyDown += KeyDown;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this [online tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to convert your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Form1
{

    System.DateTime dteStart;
    System.DateTime dteFinish;

    TimeSpan span;

    public void KeyDown(System.Object Sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.Q:
                Label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                dteStart = DateAndTime.Now();
                break;
            case Keys.W:
                Label2.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case Keys.E:
                Label3.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case Keys.R:
                Label4.BackColor = Color.Green;
                dteFinish = DateAndTime.Now();
                span = dteFinish.Subtract(dteStart);
                Label5.Text = span.ToString();

                break;
        }

    }


    public void KeyUp(System.Object Sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.Q:
                Label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Keys.W:
                Label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Keys.E:
                Label3.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Keys.R:
                Label4.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        KeyUp += KeyUp;
        KeyDown += KeyDown;
    }
}
```